# Button with custom background, text inside - C++ Builder

Tags: delphi, button, c++builder, tms

I want to create a button with a custom background, and text inside. (at execution)

But text go next to picture, never inside.

[image: Button and text next to it]

Do you know any way to do that ?

For information, I can use all TMS component pack

Comment: Create a control. Then paint the I age first, and the text on top of it. Perhaps subclassing a button control and taking over its painting.

Comment: I haven't time for this until now and You already accepted my answer but I just added new edit with a better approach (tested on VCL).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TSpeedButton` have `Glyph` property but **IIRC** they do not combine `Caption` and `Glyph` together. Fortunately you can create your glyphs programatically on the run using `Graphics::TBitmap` using your background image and render text on top of it ... I am not Delphi coder but in builder it would look like this:

```cpp
Graphics::TBitmap *bmp=new Graphics::TBitmap;
bmp->LoadFromFile("button_background.bmp");
bmp->Canvas->Font->Color=clWhite;
bmp->Canvas->Brush->Style=bsClear;
AnsiString s="caption1"
int x=(bmp->Width-bmp->Canvas->TextWidth(s))/2;
int y=(bmp->Height-bmp->Canvas->TextHeight(s))/2;
bmp->TextOutA(x,y,s);
bmp->SaveToFile("button1.bmp");
delete bmp;
```

So you can create a utility that creates all the glyphs you need which you then use in the **IDE** for your project. I never tried to load the glyphs on the runtime but there might be a way (to do this directly in the target App init).

**[Edit1] Finaly got some time to test**

The Glyph property is bitmap so you can load from file directly ... no need to new/delete. In case you want to have something more robust take a look at this. I created empty new form app with few `TSpeedButtons` on it and set their position size and `Caption` liek this:

[image: IDE designer]

And I used seamless texture as background (so I can have any button size without rescaling problems ...):

[image: texture]

And init my buttons on the runtime like this:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void bt_init(TSpeedButton *bt,Graphics::TBitmap *bmp)
    {
    int x,y,xs,ys;
    AnsiString s;
    // clear caption
    s=bt->Caption; bt->Caption="";
    // prepare glyph
    bt->Glyph->PixelFormat=bmp->PixelFormat;
    bt->Glyph->SetSize(bt->Width,bt->Height);
    // render seamless background (repeat texture)
    xs=bmp->Width;
    ys=bmp->Height;
    for (y=0;y<bt->Width;y+=ys)
     for (x=0;x<bt->Width;x+=xs)
      bt->Glyph->Canvas->Draw(x,y,bmp);
    // set transparent color
    bt->Glyph->Canvas->Pixels[0][bt->Glyph->Height-1]=clBlack;
    // render caption
    bt->Glyph->Canvas->Font->Color=clWhite;
    bt->Glyph->Canvas->Font->Style=TFontStyles()<<fsBold;
    bt->Glyph->Canvas->Brush->Style=bsClear;
    x=(bt->Glyph->Width-bt->Glyph->Canvas->TextWidth(s))/2;
    y=(bt->Glyph->Height-bt->Glyph->Canvas->TextHeight(s))/2;
    bt->Glyph->Canvas->TextOutA(x,y,s);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner):TForm(Owner)
    {
    Graphics::TBitmap *bmp=new Graphics::TBitmap;
    bmp->LoadFromFile("button.bmp");
    bmp->PixelFormat=pf32bit;
    bt_init(SpeedButton1,bmp);
    bt_init(SpeedButton2,bmp);
    bt_init(SpeedButton3,bmp);
    bt_init(SpeedButton4,bmp);
    delete bmp;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can add the border render too (another texture ...). Also you can change the Caption rendering (bigger font or colored border to enhance contrast). Here preview:

[image: preview]

Beware that bottom left corner of the final glyph holds transparent color. So if you do not use it set it with color not used in the texture to avoid artifacts.

Also take a look at this:

- [What's good algorithm for getting color to make text on image outstanding?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30421822/2521214)

for some text visual improvement ideas.